# Linux user in Jenkins and mounting to remote server

Tags: linux, jenkins, mount

**My question:**
What user does Jenkins use when running maven jobs. And what user is used when Jenkins is using a mounted share? I believe that this user doesn't have the right access. And due to security reasons I cant access the Jenkins machine and can't change access on the remote machine to verify my theory.

**Background:**

I have an Arquillian test case which is invoked by Jenkins through Maven/JUnit. Arquillian is supposed to deploy the war-file created to a remote machine. So far, so good. "wlsHome" below in the arquillian.xml file is mounted on the Jenkins machine to the remote machine.

```
<configuration>
<property name="wlsHome">/global/xxx/xxxx/xxxxx/</property>
 <property name="adminUrl">t3://xxxxxx:8200</property>
 <property name="adminUserName">yyyyy</property>
 <property name="adminPassword">xxxxx</property>
 <property name="target">zzzzz</property>
</configuration>
```

Now this doesn't work and I get an NoClassDefFoundError

```
WARNING: weblogic.Deployer terminated abnormally with exit code 1
Feb 11, 2014 9:48:27 AM org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicDeployerClient forkWebLogicDeployer
INFO: The output of the weblogic.Deployer process was:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weblogic/utils/Debug
at weblogic.Deployer.<clinit>(Deployer.java:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if below jars are available on the target machine? :

a. BEA_HOME/wlserver/server/lib/wlclient.jar (not wlfullclient.jar)
b. BEA_HOME/modules/com.bea.core.descriptor.wl_1.3.3.0.jar

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. wlclient.jar is there, and com.bea.core.descriptor is also there, but with another version (1.4.0.0.jar)

Comment: Can you check if the jars are populated correctly in system env paths?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. It turns out that our wlsHome was set to

/blabla/wlserver10.3/wlserver_10.3   and not /blabla/wlserver10.3